# Command to find out which program is keeping ubuntu awake or waking it up

Tags: suspend, power-management, wakeup

Windows has powercfg -lastwake and powercfg -requests to find out what last woke up windows or which program last requested keep awake. Is there Ubuntu equivalent?

Comment: [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132115/how-to-find-reason-a-notebook-wakes-up) post might help you